# Battle.net Launcher Crashes, typical fix not working. World of Warcraft once run in 64-bit, now saying memory can't be "read"

Tags: 14.04, wine, games

The typical dbghel fix for wine is NOT WORKING. It worked for a couple days, and then all of a sudden I'm getting Blizzard Errors when I boot up Battle.net AND World of Warcraft (Battle.net launcher stays operational long enough for me to click Play for WoW before it crashes, only to have WoW crash when I try to log into the game from the character screen.).

Any help is greatly, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

I checked Additional Drivers, and it turned out that the Graphics Driver was the issue. Opened terminal and ran:

sudo apt-get install nvidia-331

AND IT BE WORKIN.